# group join with lambda in c#

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to make a join query with lambda
this is my query:

```
        var query = db.SampleSeries.GroupJoin(db.Projects, seri => seri.projectId, prjct => prjct.projectId,
            (seri, prjct) => new ListSeriesProjectViewModel()
            {
                nameProject = prjct.ownerA,
                address = prjct.address,
                seriesId = seri.seriesId,
                seriesId = seri.getDate
            }).ToList();
```

but I have error in

nameProject = prjct.ownerA
address = prjct.address

in fact not recognize the fields of Projects.
an you help me?

what is the problem in this query?

Comment: Can you share the model class for `ListSeriesProjectViewModel`? And what is your expected result? And you are assigning value to same property `seriesId`, are you sure it is correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the result selector, you are accessing properties directly from prjct which is not correct, because with a GroupJoin, prjct is actually an IEnumerable of the matched records. You might need to use some aggregate function or other operation on it.

You have duplicate properties (seriesId) in your result object initializer.

Here's a correction assuming you want just the first or default project match for each series:

```
var query = db.SampleSeries.GroupJoin(db.Projects,
                                  seri => seri.projectId, 
                                  prjct => prjct.projectId,
        (seri, prjctCollection) => new 
        {
            seri = seri,
            prjct = prjctCollection.FirstOrDefault() // assuming you want just one project per series
        })
        .Select(result => new ListSeriesProjectViewModel()
        {
            nameProject = result.prjct?.ownerA,
            address = result.prjct?.address,
            seriesId = result.seri.seriesId,
            getDate = result.seri.getDate // assuming getDate is a property of seri and you want to keep it in the ViewModel
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: And how is about add 'Where' in this query?

Comment: before writting groupjoin , 
var query = db.SampleSeries
        .Where(seri => /* your condition here */)
        .GroupJoin(db.Projects,
                   seri => seri.projectId, ......

For example, if you want to filter SampleSeries where a certain property meets a criteria, you'd replace it with something like seri => seri.someProperty == "someValue"

Answer (score 0):

Would be great if you could share your expected result for the data.

From [IEnumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupjoin-4(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-2))-system-func((-1-2))-system-func((-0-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-3)))):

```cs
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult> GroupJoin<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult> (this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, 
    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner> inner, 
    Func<TOuter,TKey> outerKeySelector, 
    Func<TInner,TKey> innerKeySelector, 
    Func<TOuter,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>,TResult> resultSelector);
```

`prjct` would return the value of `IEnumerable<Project>` type.

---

1. If you expect the result containing the mapping/joining between both `SampleSeries` and `Project` entities (1-to-1), you should look for `Join` instead of `GroupJoin`.

```cs
var query = db.SampleSeries.Join(db.Projects, 
    seri => seri.projectId, 
    prjct => prjct.projectId,
    (seri, prjct) => new ListSeriesProjectViewModel()
    {
        nameProject = prjct.ownerA,
        address = prjct.address,
        seriesId = seri.seriesId,
        getDate = seri.getDate  // Incorrect assign value to same property within object initializer
    }).ToList();
```

2. If you expect the result with the series and its linked Project entities (1-to-many), `GroupJoin` is the way to achieve it.

```
public class SeriesProjectModel
{
    public string NameProject { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class ListSeriesProjectViewModel
{
    public List<SeriesProjectModel> Projects { get; set; }
    public int SeriesId { get; set; }
    public DateTime GetDate { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var query = db.SampleSeries.GroupJoin(db.Projects, 
    seri => seri.projectId, 
    prjct => prjct.projectId,
    (seri, prjct) => new ListSeriesProjectViewModel()
    {
        Projects = prjct.Select(x => new SeriesProjectModel
        {
            NameProject = x.ownerA,
            Address = x.address
        }).ToList(),
        SeriesId = seri.seriesId,
        GetDate = seri.getDate
    }).ToList();
```

*Side notes: Would encourage you to apply all the property names with Pascal Case by following the C# naming conventions.*